# How to stop arrow keys scrolling in two DIVs in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, html

I have a **JSP** page with various **DIVs**, one containing a table.

I can select a row in the table and then change that selection using the arrow keys.
That is fine.

I select a row in the table and press a button which causes a hidden `DIV` to be displayed.

This new `DIV` contains a `SELECT` pulldown.
If I click on the `SELECT` pulldown and then use the arrow keys to change my selection that 
does indeed change. However I also find that my selection in the original table also
changes.

How can I stop this ?

Comment: This sounds a lot more like a browser problem than a JSP problem. What client are you using to test this page? Can you post the output that actually causes this issue?

Comment: The problem occurred in IE & Firefox.
It caused by the pages using some javascript methods that register for keyclicks and then took appropiate action. 

I have changed the function that make the hidden DIVs visible and invisible to set a variable to true/false which the keyclick method reads.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue called event bubbling. Most javascript frameworks have a way to stop this behaviour. The exact solution however depends on your sourcecode, which you didn't provide in your wuestion.

Ie. jqueries way: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/